# IBM Cloud: How to find region identifier for location name?

Tags: command-line-interface, ibm-cloud

[IBM Cloud recently updated global location names (regions)](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/overview/whats-new/index.html#whatsnew). How can I programmatically (CLI or API) find out what the new names are and how they related to region identifiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the command line the simplest way is using the `ibmcloud regions` command:

```
>> ibmcloud regions 
Listing regions...

Name       Display name    Customer   Deployment   Type   
au-syd     Sydney          IBM        Production   public   
jp-tok     Tokyo                                      
eu-de      Frankfurt       IBM        Production   public   
eu-gb      London          IBM        Production   public   
us-south   Dallas          IBM        Production   public   
us-east    Washington DC   IBM        Production   public
```

Another option is to use a GET request on `mccp.<region>.bluemix.net/V2/regions` (you need to know at least one region identifier:

```
curl mccp.eu-de.bluemix.net/V2/regions
```

This returns a JSON object with the available regions, their identifier and display name, API endpoint information and more.